# Getting a noSuchMethodException

Tags: java, recursion

I'm programming a recursive definition of the sine function in Java using it's Taylor approximation, but getting a `noSuchMethodException` upon running the code. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void Main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("The approximate sine of pi over 2 with an accuracy index of ten is:");
    System.out.println(Mathematics.recursiveSine(Math.PI/2,10));
}

public static double recursiveSine(double value, int index){
    if(index==1) {
        return value;
    }
    return ((double) ((-1)^(2*index + 1)) * Math.pow(value,2*index + 1)/factorial(2*index + 1)) + recursiveSine(value, index-1);
}

public static int factorial(int value){
    return value==1 ? value : value*factorial(value-1);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, the main method is called `main`, not `Main` .

Comment: `main` must have a lower-case `m`.

Comment: `Mathematics.` is unnecessary if it gets called in the same class

Comment: You should use eclipse IDE. It will detect all such problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main method needs to be lowercase.

**You have**

```
public static void Main(String[] args){
```

**Should be**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```